# timeago.js with datatable and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, timeago

I am displaying data of `dates` in my datatable using [timeago.js](http://timeago.org/) along with the use of PHP. The problem is some data specifically `dates` in my datatables are missing when I click on the next page of my datatable. I don't know how to fix this, please help.

This is my Datatable-Table on its first page

```
Date_Joined        Username
8 minutes ago       john
10 minutes ago      jake
20 minutes ago      jay
```

And this is the next page of my datatable showing no date

```
Date_Joined        Username
                     may
                     june
                     april
```

and if i click on my datatable to view 10, 25, 50, 100 pages

```
Date_Joined        Username
8 minutes ago       john
10 minutes ago      jake
20 minutes ago      jay
                    may
                    june
                    april
```

Please I really need your help.

Comment: I find "time ago" values really annoying, I'd much rather have dates and times.

Comment: Datatables does not refresh the site when next page is clicked. It just reads, caches and re-organizes the data on page load (assuming you have not dealt with that). You need to build a script that re-fetches the data on click if you do not have one. Either way I am guessing you want to use draw() https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code inside your  tag. It should work when you click the next page.

inside `$("")` add the `table id` and add `_paginate` next to it

```
$("#simpledatatable_paginate").click(function(){
            jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
    });
```

While the above code works only for the pagination. This code here will allow you to solve your problem. Replace the above code with this code:

> $("#simpledatatable").on('draw.dt', function(){
>                   jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
>       });

add this code before you iniatilize your datatable.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've got it working but i have another problem when im directly clicking on sort in the datatables or showing page 10, 20,25, 100 etc.

Comment: @Jah I've updated the code. I hope i answered your problem :)

Comment: @Jah, Glad i'm able to help